# Excel template file to import data from the older system to AX 2012 using the excel add-in

Tags: axapta, etl, excel-addins, dynamics-ax-2012

I would like to know if there is somewhere a excel template to download that you should fill in to import data from excel to AX 2012. 
For example **Customers** and **Global Address Book** spreadsheet.

Our current plan is to import the Global Address Book first and then associate the address as a Customer, and later on import the Customer data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on a resource here: http://axlearning.com/excel-addinax2012/

The original source is [Alex Anikiev](http://ax2012exceldataimport.blogspot.dk/).

Comment: It seems that the template is built for you when you use excel.
This is built using drag and drop. And these templates are used per `table`, instead of per `entity`. Thanks @Jan B. Kjeldsen